# Coq: unfolding class instances

Tags: typeclass, coq

How do I unfold class instances in Coq? It seems to be possible only when the instance doesn't include a proof, or something. Consider this:

```
Class C1 (t:Type) := {v1:t}.
Class C2 (t:Type) := {v2:t;c2:v2=v2}.

Instance C1_nat: C1 nat:= {v1:=4}.

Instance C2_nat: C2 nat:= {v2:=4}.
trivial.
Qed.

Theorem thm1 : v1=4.
unfold v1.
unfold C1_nat.
trivial.
Qed.

Theorem thm2 : v2=4.
unfold v2.
unfold C2_nat.
trivial.
Qed.
```

`thm1` is proved, but I can't prove `thm2`; it complains at the `unfold C2_nat` step with `Error: Cannot coerce C2_nat to an evaluable reference.`.

What's going on? How do I get to `C2_nat`'s definition of `v2`?

Comment: I think this transparent-opaque feature exists to allow speeding up reduction. You should make opaque the parts of your programs that don't contribute to the output, that contribute only to the type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ended the definition of `C2_nat` with `Qed`. Definitions ending with `Qed` are opaque and cannot be unfolded. Write the following instead

```
Instance C2_nat: C2 nat:= {v2:=4}.
  trivial.
Defined.
```

and your proof finishes without problems.