# reasoning about typeclass instance that has been picked up in a theorem?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

```
Class Action (Actor: Type) (Acted: Type) :=
  {
    act : Actor -> Acted -> Acted;
    someProof: forall (a: Actor), a = a;
  }.

Instance natListAction: Action nat (list nat) :=
  {
    act (n: nat) (l: list nat) := cons n l;
  }.
Proof.
    auto.
Qed.


Lemma natListAction_is_cons: forall (n: nat) (l: list nat),
    act n l = cons n l.
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold act.
  (** I cannot unfold it, since I have someProof.
   If I remove this, this unfold works **)
  unfold natListAction.
Abort.
```

What I actually want is this: because I know that `act` resolves to `natListAction`, I know that `act = cons`. Hence, the lemma should go through.

If I do not have the `someProof` in my `Action` class, then I can `unfold natListAction` and stuff works. But now, I am unable to do so.

However, how do I convince coq that `act = cons` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on another SO thread: [Coq: unfolding typeclass instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111816/coq-unfolding-class-instances).

Ending the `Proof` section with a `Qed` makes it opaque. Instead, end the proof with a `Defined` and it will go through.

For the sake of completeness, here is the final proof:

```
Class Action (Actor: Type) (Acted: Type) :=
  {
    act : Actor -> Acted -> Acted;
    someProof: forall (a: Actor), a = a;
  }.

Instance natListAction: Action nat (list nat) :=
  {
    act (n: nat) (l: list nat) := cons n l;
  }.
Proof.
  auto.
  (** vvv Notice the change! this is now "Defined" vvv **)
Defined.


Lemma natListAction_is_cons: forall (n: nat) (l: list nat),
    act n l = cons n l.
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold act.
  unfold natListAction.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Observe that `reflexivity` alone is enough to do the proof.

Comment: ah, nice. Because `reflexivity` simplifies things?

Comment: Correct. `reflexivity` is a pretty complex tactic with [lots of fallbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46227271/2747511). So it can do `intros` and the rest of it follows by computation, which includes unfoldings a.k.a. `delta` reduction.

Comment: Technically, the reason `reflexivity` can solve this is because (a) `reflexivity` does `intros`, and (b), the term `fun n l => eq_refl` typechecks as a proof of your theorem.  It is not that `reflexivity` is doing `delta` reduction here, but that judgmental equality is modulo delta.